# How to test the distributional assumption are reasonable or not?

Tags: distributions, estimation

I have a set of data and want to estimate the underlying statistical distribution. Basically I could assume it follows normal, F-, whatever distribution. But how can I conclude which distribution is better?

Comment: You can fit a few generalized linear models containing only an intercept and pick the best using AIC or AICc.

Comment: Better at what? (Note also your title and your body text are asking quite different questions.)

Answer (score 0):

Using [Bayesian settings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_statistics), the problem is fairly easy.

Given a model $M$ with distribution function $F()$ and parameters $\vec{\theta}$, update  the model with the data you have and derive a posterior probability.

Then, using [marginal likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_likelihood#Bayesian_model_comparison), you could see what model fits the data best regardless of the parameters.